# Python3 flask_admin : How to avoid unauthorized users view the admin page?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Recently, I'm using python flask to build a simple website
But I'm confuse about how to avoid users who is unauthorized from seen the admin page

Although override `is_visible` and `is_accessible` function can avoid unauthorized users to see or edit data in database
But the admin page still can be seen by all users
I want to redirect unauthorized users to index page when they try to go into admin page, how can I do?

Here's my `AdminModeView` code with python3

```py
# admin panel permission setting
class AdminModelView(ModelView):
    def is_visible(self):
        try:
            if(current_user.auth == 'Admin'):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except:
            return False

    def is_accessible(self):
        try:
            if(current_user.auth == 'Admin'):
                can_create = True
                can_edit = True
                can_delete = True
                return True
            else:
                return False
        except:
            return False
    
    def inaccessible_callback(self, name, **kwargs):
        # redirect to login page if user doesn't have access
        return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from flask_admin import AdminIndexView
from flask_login import login_required


class DashboardView(AdminIndexView):
    @login_required
    def _handle_view(self, name, **kwargs):
        # the magic lives in the _handle_view function.
        # inside here, you can check if the user is authenticated, etc.

        super(DashboardView, self)._handle_view(name, **kwargs)
```

i actually just got this from some code i had implemented before. but what happens is that the AdminIndexView is the view for the /admin route. the _handle_view function is executed when the user access the /admin route. with that in mind, you can do redirects and other stuff with the current_user object

[docs](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_base/#default-view)

Comment: Could you add some explanation to this answer? While code-only answers are okay, some explanation might help readers understand your code better.